# How to fix fluidsynth: error: Unknown integer parameter 'synth.sample-rate'

Tags: python, fluidsynth

I am getting the (non-fatal) error on `pm.fluidsynth(fs=16000)` where pm is a `pretty_midi.PrettyMIDI`. I found https://github.com/nwhitehead/pyfluidsynth/issues/37 and applied the changes there to my `fluidsynth.py` file, but this didn't fix it. I am unsure how to progress from here.

## Additional Information

I tried to follow this tutorial https://www.tensorflow.org/tutorials/audio/music_generation . I am using pycharm and I installed all packages into a single virtual environment.